# OQL all instances from a package

Tags: jvm, oql

Is it possible in `OQL` to retrieve all the objects that belongs to a package? Or can I query with `wildcards`?

As @haridsv suggested I tried:

```
SELECT * from "com.example.*"
```

and

```
SELECT a from "com\.example\..*"
```

but in `VisualVM` it complaints that no such package exists.

Even

```
SELECT a from "java.io.File" a
```

Fails.

Thanks!

ssedano.

Comment: in jvisualvm it seems you need to write SELECT using small letters, ie "select".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in [VisualVM OQL help](http://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html).

```
select filter(heap.classes(), "/com.example./(it.name)")
```

Comment: :2 TypeError: /java.awt./ is not a function

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expression like this:

```
SELECT * from "<packagename>.*"
```

If the package name is "java.io" you would use:

```
SELECT * from "java\.io\..*"
```

Note the quotes around the regex and how the dots in the path are protected.

Comment: Using the OQL console in visualvm those selects does not work. but thanks for  answer !!

Comment: I was suggesting OQL for Eclipse MAT, where as the OQL syntax for VisualVM is quite different. My apologies if I missed to see your requirements clearly.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that I should clarify, may be because I had my head deep in a heap analysis with MAT :)

Comment: @haridsv: I was using Android's memory analyzer and your queries were exactly what I needed. I found the example given in the selected answer and it doesn't work but your suggestion did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From VisualVM limited documentation:

- select all classes that have name pattern java.net.*

`select filter(heap.classes(), "/java.net./.test(it.name)")`

https://visualvm.github.io/documentation.html

The trick is in the "test(it.name)"