# VisualVM 1.3.8 OQL - TypeError: [RegExp /java.lang./] is not a function

Tags: java, heap-dump, oql

When executing below OQL, it gives ***TypeError: [RegExp /java.lang./] is not a function***

```
select filter(heap.classes(), "/java.lang./(it.name)")
```

Should that work? Refer to [OQL all instances from a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385185/oql-all-instances-from-a-package)

Also, may I know if OQL is a "standard" for analyzing heap dump?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that:

```
select filter(heap.classes(), "/java.lang./.exec(it.name)")
```

works. My OQL-foo is not that strong, but I'd hazard a guess that it relates to [Javascript error regex not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061123/javascript-error-regex-not-a-function).

## Update

I seem to be able to reproduce the issue on Java 8 (which uses Nashorn), but not on Java 7 or below (which uses Rhino). This makes sense, as Nashorn implements the ES5 behaviour where RegExp is not a function, whereas Rhino implements the old Mozilla behaviour, where is it.